# Using cron to run reusable github workflow

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to run a reusable GitHub action with a cron job. I am trying to see if it is even possible. I am running into an issue where the workflow doesn't show up in actions. (This is on a testing branch, not the main branch).

```
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: 0 23 1 * *
jobs:
  hcpkgrelease:
    uses: owner/repo/.github/workflows/hc_release.yml@workflow_changes
```

Comment: The workflow needs to exist on the default branch to appear on the repo `Actions` tab. Did you try adding it there to check?

Answer (score 0):

Workflows have to exist on `main` or `master` branch to be taken into account. You can overwrite them on branches, but to execute them you have to keep a copy of them on the default branch.

Check Github [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule) - for `scheduled` event GITHUB_REF is only `Default branch`.

For all other trigger types, you usually have a note:

```
Note: This event will only trigger a workflow run if the workflow file is on the default branch
```

Comment: I won't be able to add it right now (team approval needed).

Comment: How would you run a cron job using a reusable workflow if you can use runs-on and uses in the same job?  
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron: 5 0 * * *
    
jobs:
  testing:
    if: github.event.schedule != '5 0 * * *'
    uses: owner/repo/.github/workflows/main.yml@main       My main concern now is cron's normally use runs-on and steps but reusable only take uses. I want this cron job to trigger this reusable workflow.